# How to remove nodes having attribute value different from given using XSLT?

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xpath, web-config

In given pretty simple and standard config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:env="urn:schemas-test-env">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Name" value="Value" />
        <add key="Name" value="Value" env:name="Dev" />
        <add key="Name" value="Value" env:name="QA" />
    </appSettings>

    <!-- rest of the config -->

</configuration>
```

I want to remove all nodes `<add />` where `@env:name != $env` using XSLT? My main problem is to leave the rest of the config as it is.

What I have so far:

```
<!-- populated by inline C# code -->
<xsl:variable name="env" select="code:GetEnvironment()" />

<!-- Leave as is -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Remove non-matching nodes -->
<xsl:template match="configuration/appSettings/add">
    ???
</xsl:template>
```

I have one more stub:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(@env:name)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'no env'" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="./@env:name = $env">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Env eq var'" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="'Env neq var'" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:env="urn:schemas-test-env">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:param name="env" select="'QA'"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="add">
  <xsl:if test="not(@env:name = $env)">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<configuration xmlns:env="urn:schemas-test-env">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Name" value="Value" />
        <add key="Name" value="Value" env:name="Dev" />
        <add key="Name" value="Value" env:name="QA" />
    </appSettings>
    <!-- rest of the config -->
</configuration>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<configuration xmlns:env="urn:schemas-test-env">
   <appSettings>
      <add key="Name" value="Value"/>
      <add key="Name" value="Value" env:name="Dev"/>
   </appSettings><!-- rest of the config -->
</configuration>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0+ solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:env="urn:schemas-test-env">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:param name="env" select="'QA'"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="add[@env:name = $env]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

XSLT 2.0 differs from XSLT 1.0 in that it allows variable references as part of the predicates of a match pattern. This feature makes it possible to have just a single, empty overriding template.

Comment: Unfortunately 2.0 throws exception `Operation could destabilize the runtime` in Visual Studio XSLT Debug.

Comment: I want to achieve an opposite thing: leave only env-empty and env-equal to given, i.e. "" and "Dev" when env=Dev. Not vice versa. So I use `not(@env:name != $env)` and it works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: [Online](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/8B1eKo) 2.0 version doesn't work too. Don't you know why may it happen?

Comment: And you're an XSLT guru. Most probably you know or at least suspect :)

Comment: @abatishchev, Visual Studio uses an XSLT 1.0 processor only. You need to use a compliant (not "cake") XSLT 2.0 processor with XSLT 2.0 transformations.

Comment: How can I remove attribute namespace containing too? So output xml would be look like there were neither namespaces nor transformation. Thanks!

Comment: And namespace declaration too. `<exclude-result-prefixes="env" />` doesn't work by some reason.

Comment: @abatishchev, Seems you want to ask a new SO question? Please, do so, and I will be glad to help.